# Mozilla progress style

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with my progressbar..
In chrome, the value of the progress bar is red.. I did that with CSS...
But in Mozilla the value of the progress bar is just kinda grey..

```
    progress[value] {
  width: 250px;
  height: 10px;

}
progress[value] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;

  width: 250px;
  height: 24px;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
progress[value]::-moz-progress-value {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
    opacity:0.6;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:red;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

The -moz- value of the progress bar must be red, thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you are telling to be grey `background-color: #eee;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference from css-tricks:

"Firefox provides a single pseudo class (`-moz-progress-bar`) we can use to target the progress bar value. This means that we cannot style the background of the container in Firefox."

Like said, the `-moz-progress-bar` refers to the value itself, so making it red should make the value as what you wanted. `-moz-progress-value` doesn't exist.